# CakePHP requestAction catch error when url not exists

Tags: url, cakephp, exception

I try to catch error when the requested url does not exist in my application when I use requestAction($url);
with try-catch block, requested wrongs url continue to be loaded;

Please tell me if there is an other solution to test if the url exist, or if the file exist in cakephp dir (my url can be composed of a plugin name).

my actual code:

```
$url = $appliUrl .  $cron['Cron']['plugin'] . '/'. $cron['Cron']['controller'] . '/' . $cron['Cron']['action'];
if (!empty($cron['Cron']['params'])) {
    $params = explode(',', $cron['Cron']['params']);
    foreach ($params as $param)
        $url .= '/' . $param;
}
try{
    $output = $this->requestAction($url);
}catch (Exception $e){
    $output = "error in the url : ".$url;
}
```

Comment: What are you expecting the requestAction to return? If it doesn't exist it is going to return a 404 page, which is still a valid request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a variety of methods to accomplish this. In this example, use cURL.

```
function url_exists($url) {
    if (!$fp = curl_init($url)) return false;
    return true;
}
```

Then you can wrap your $output in an if block checking for the url.

```
if (url_exists($url)) {
   $output = $this->requestAction($url);
}
```

*EDIT*

Make sure you put the function in a lib or your bootstrap for access. Don't just stick it in your controller like that :)

**ANOTHER EDIT**

```
<?php 
$ch = curl_init('http://yoururl/'); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 1); 
$c = curl_exec($ch); 
echo curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
```

Comment: This function always return me true. Maybe because cakephp generate error html page ?! 
Any other solution ?

Comment: Inspect the header response that you get back from it. Are you looking to catch 404 errors?

Comment: yes i want to catch 404 errors, maybe i must send headers request before the requestAction ? any idea?